# How to avoid Outlook's security warning on a .ics file

Tags: outlook, google-calendar-api, icalendar, ical-dotnet, ical.net

I am creating a .ics file using iCal.Net. THe file is correct and works. But when I go to open it, I'm using Outlook on Windows, I get:

[image]

But I get invites all the time in Outlook that I accept without this warning. So I looked on meetup.com and what it has for adding to the calendar is:

[image]

So, do I need to create 4 different calendar files so users can then select the appropriate one? Or is there a way to create a .ics that all the calendar apps accept without a security warning?

Comment: Have you tried to compare the .ics files content to understand what exactly triggers the security issue?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev I think they're different file types (and contents). Because it looks like the iCalendar format does not support rich text and Outlook calendar events do support rich text. But I haven't been able to find anything on it searching (so far).

Comment: I'd suggest posting both there and asking people whether they can find any difference between them.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is an acknowledged bug by Microsoft

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/outlook-prompts-security-notice-opening-ics-files-after-installing-protections-for-microsoft-outlook-information-disclosure-vulnerability-released-dec-12-2023-df8647ef-1828-421b-a266-79120b6190bd